# How to create a SharePoint 2010 workflow with an email link that will be removing items in the list

Tags: 2010, workflow, sharepoint-addin

Is it possible to deliver a link through the Work Flow email, which will delete item in library when clicked. I have seen a system that does something like this using application pages, I am on the right track?
To further explain, this system is to monitor anybody that clicks a link that is being delivered through the email.